# How to add items to new list if cell value > 0

Tags: excel, list

Im looking for a way to organize my shopping list for my food truck/shop better. I currently just manually keep track of my items and print my shopping list when I go to the store. However, this method prints 2 pages of my list when I only need 10 items. Im looking to add a function that would add needed food items to my "shopping list" when I enter the value needed as being more than 0. Is there a function to accomplish this?

Comment: what language you use ?

Comment: Help us out: tell us what language you're using, and show us your code. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I tried posting a pic and assumed you would be able to tell from that. However, it denied the pic. :(. Im actually just trying to use excel. I thought I have done this previously but cant recall how.

Comment: If your complete list is on one sheet, iterate through that, then output the items that have values > 0 to another sheet, then print that secondary sheet.

Comment: That's exactly what it was @pnuts. Thank you. I couldn't remember the function to use to perform this. Thank you so much